# Проблема с валидацией действий через VK API 5.0

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема с валидацией действий через ВКонтакте. 
Дело в том, что  начиная с версии API 5.0 [ввели новый метод валидации](https://vk.com/dev/need_validation) (ранее была CAPTCHA, с которой отлично работалось).

Слегка не понял момент в документации:

> **redirect_uri** — специально составленный адрес, который необходимо открыть в браузере для прохождения процедуры валидации.

Открыть его нужно со стороны пользователя, или со стороны сервера? Я попробовал оба варианта. Получил ссылку, к примеру:

> https://m.vk.com/login?act=security_check&api_hash=0449ff3ed0d1dc11

Перехожу на неё в браузере — всё как в документации, получаю после редиректа ссылку:

> [https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#success=1&access_token=мойтокен](https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#success=1&access_token=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD)

Причём, токен не отличается от того, что был до этого, хотя в документации идёт речь о новом токене. Но так или иначе, получили *success=1*, значит, всё должно работать? Пробую вновь отправить запрос — аналогичная ситуация: возвращает ошибку и требует валидацию пройти.

Я уже попробовал и с сайта через `file_get_contents+$_REQUEST` получить запрос — ВК не вернул ничего, хотя судя по документации "пользователь" сам открывает ссылку в браузере.

Уже всё перепробовал раз 5. Отписал в поддержку социальной сети также, но возможно я уже где-то ошибаюсь и кто-то встречался с этим. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

UPD:  Что странно, что ссылку в **`redirect_uri`** передает через мобильную версию, т.е. через `m.vk.com`, хотя в документации просто через `vk.com`, и при попытке убрать с `redirect_uri` `m.` и оставить ссылку формата `vk.com`, после того, как пытаешься перейти по ней в браузере — попадаю на страницу ВКонтакте.

Для отправки запроса использую **`file_get_contents`**, а не cURL. Попробую сейчас cURL.

**UPD**: Попробовал, никаких изменений: также `m.vk.com`. Скорее всего дело и не в этом. Код:

```
function callMethod($request, $params) {

    $c=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($c);

    if($result === false) {
        $result = curl_error($c);
    }
    curl_close($c);

    return $result;
}
```

**UPD**: Проблема всё ещё не решена: от ВК [нет ответа](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecNXQ.jpg) :(
Возможно найдется добрая душа, которая сделает вопрос конкурсным? У меня не хватает репутации для минимального порога.

Comment: Проблема в том, что постоянно вылезает требование пройти "валидацию" даже после того, как вы её прошли? Я правильно понял? Если да, то у аккаунта, с которого осуществляются запросы, подтвержден номер телефона? В некоторых случаях ВК не дает работать с API аккаунтам, которые не подтвердили номер телефона или не врубили двухфракторную авторизацию.

Comment: @terron, привязан. Двухфакторная авторизация выключена. Да, проблема именно в постоянном требовании валидации даже после десятка её успешных прохождений.

Comment: Попробуйте включить её.

Comment: @terron, вроде как, кроме токена, ничего толком не изменилось. Проблема осталась, увы. Поддержка всё ещё молчит.

Answer (score 2):

Была точно такая же проблема. ВК выдаёт такую ошибку, когда вы заходите из нового необычного места, и надо открывать ту ссылку именно из того места. Например, когда вы используете прокси и пытаетесь зайти в вк, то он попросит Вас подтвердить номер.

Получается что мы получили токен с одного ip адреса (со стороны сервера), а использовать его пытаемся со стороны пользователя, у которого другой ip адрес.

Я писал в тех. поддержку, увы ничем они не помогают:

> Ошибка появляется в двух случаях — либо если ip-адрес является
>   «неожиданным» для того аккаунта, с которого ведется работа
>   (собственно, поэтому ошибка и называется «вход из подозрительного
>   места»), либо если речь идет о попытке использовать на сервере токен,
>   который получен в клиентском приложении по схеме
>   vk.com/dev/auth_mobile

То есть теоретически когда мы делаем запрос повторно, вк просит подтвердить номер, но как это сделать с помощью API не понятно.

Я решил проблему двумя путями:

- путем перевода приложения из стэндэлон в веб-сайт.
- использовал это - https://github.com/Yashko/vk-validation-node

Comment: Написал ещё раз в тех. поддержку. Ответ опять стандартный: Ошибка появляется в двух случаях — либо если ip-адрес является «неожиданным» для того аккаунта, с которого ведется работа (собственно, поэтому ошибка и называется «вход из подозрительного места»), либо если речь идет о попытке использовать на сервере токен, который получен в клиентском приложении по схеме vk.com/dev/auth_mobile

Comment: Ввели новый функционал, который работает не понятно.