# Laravel перестала работать авторизация ВКонтакте

Tags: laravel, авторизация, oauth, laravel5

Спустя месяц перестала работать авторизация ВКонтакте на Laravel проекте.
Использовал пакет Socialite.
Сейчас при входе вот такую ошибку выдает:

> InvalidStateException in VkontakteProvider.php line 92:

Посмотрел что возвращает ВК, оказалось что 302 ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понял ошибка из за того что кончилось время жизни токена.

Ошибку выдает здесь:

```
if ($this->hasInvalidState()) {
    throw new InvalidStateException();
}
```

но моих знаний не достаточно чтобы понять почему, можете объяснить?

вот страница с ошибкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это файл `VkontakteProvider.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Socialite\Two;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class VkontakteProvider extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    protected $fields = ['uid', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'screen_name', 'photo'];

    /**
     * Unique Provider Identifier.
     */
    const IDENTIFIER = 'VKONTAKTE';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $scopes = ['email'];

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getAuthUrl($state)
    {
        return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase(
            'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize', $state
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getTokenUrl()
    {
        return 'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getUserByToken($token)
    {
        $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get(
            'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids='.$token['user_id'].'&fields='.implode(',', $this->fields).'&https=1'
        );

        $response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true)['response'][0];

        return array_merge($response, [
            'email' => Arr::get($token, 'email'),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
    {
        return (new User())->setRaw($user)->map([
            'id' => Arr::get($user, 'uid'), 'nickname' => Arr::get($user, 'screen_name'),
            'name' => trim(Arr::get($user, 'first_name')),
            'email' => Arr::get($user, 'email'), 'avatar' => Arr::get($user, 'photo'),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getTokenFields($code)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getTokenFields($code), [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function parseAccessToken($body)
    {
        return json_decode($body, true);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function user()
    {
        if ($this->hasInvalidState()) {
            throw new InvalidStateException();
        }

        $user = $this->mapUserToObject($this->getUserByToken(
            $token = $this->getAccessTokenResponse($this->getCode())
        ));

        return $user->setToken(Arr::get($token, 'access_token'))
            ->setExpiresIn(Arr::get($token, 'expires_in'));
    }

    /**
     * Set the user fields to request from Vkontakte.
     *
     * @param array $fields
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function fields(array $fields)
    {
        $this->fields = $fields;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function additionalConfigKeys()
    {
        return ['lang'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что проблема у вас та же, с которой столкнулся и я. Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590933/Проблема-с-валидацией-действий-через-vk-api-5-0/653155#653155

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, нет, не то. На сколько я понял то у меня это происходит потому что закончилось время жизни токена, и при возникновении ошибки мне как то нужно ещё раз запросить у пользователя доступ

Comment: Из ошибки видно - что на стороне бекенда метод `hasInvalidState()` возвращает `false`. Смотрите содержимое метода hasInvalidState(). Скорее всего state - это статус запроса. Если это 302(как на скрине), значит вам надо поддержать редирект при запросах, в общем что-то с запросом не так, отладьте этот запрос который шлёт PHP - узнаете причину

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не передаёте версию API. С начала 2018 года [версию API передавать необходимо](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests?f=1.%20%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0).

Вместо таких строк:

```
$response = $this->getHttpClient()->get(
    'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids='.$token['user_id'].'&fields='.implode(',', $this->fields).'&https=1'
);
```

Должны быть такие:

```
$response = $this->getHttpClient()->get(
    'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?v=5.73&user_ids='.$token['user_id'].'&fields='.implode(',', $this->fields).'&https=1'
    //                                   ^^^^^^
);
```

Аналогично во всех других местах. Версию можно передавать как в начале, так и в конце - это не важно.

Конечно, параметр версии лучше не хардкодить в каждом URL, а брать, например, из какой-то константы.

[Пример работающего класса VKontakteProvider.](https://github.com/socialite-manager/VKontakte-Provider/blob/master/src/VKontakteProvider.php#L68)